# c++ application crashed when trying to access the key from a std::map object

Tags: c++, dictionary, crash

first, I write a template log function as the following:

```
void Utils::_logMap(std::map<K, V> map) {
    cout << "===================[map]=====================\n";
    for(auto it: map) {
        auto key = it.first;
        auto val = it.second;
        cout << key << " = " << val << endl;
    }

   // testing code
   cout << "\n>>> for testing: \n";
   cout << map.at("S_WARNING_UNABLE_TO_PUT_INTO_WEREHOUSE") << endl;
   cout << map.at("S_HELLO") << endl;
   cout << map.at("S_TEST") << endl;
}
```

then I create a std::map object, and read the text content from a file(a localized language txt file with UTF-8 encoding).

```
static std::map<string, string> localizedStrings;
```

then I print out all of its key-value.

```
Utils::_logMap(localizedStrings);
```

the result shows:

```
===================[map]=====================
S_HELLO = hello123
S_WARNING_UNABLE_TO_PUT_INTO_WEREHOUSE = teest1312
S_TEST = Test777

>>> for testing:
teest1312
hello123
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: map::at:  key not found
```

the last line out_of_range exception is caused by this code:

```
cout << map.at("S_HELLO") << endl; // for testing, app will crash
```

but how can this be!!?!? the map object indeed contains a key named S_HELLO. why the app gets exception when I try to access the key via typing a constant string value!? I don't get it!

**UPDATED:**
Well, this is the primary reading content function codes:

```
string Utils::getLocalizedString(const string key) {
    LanguageType type = Application::getInstance()->getCurrentLanguage();
    const char* code = Application::getInstance()->getCurrentLanguageCode();
    cclog("language type: %d, code: %s", type, code);
    const char * fileName;
    switch (type) {
        case LanguageType::ENGLISH:
            fileName = "Localized_en.txt";
            break;
        case LanguageType::CHINESE:
            fileName = "Localized_zh.txt";
            break;
        default:
            fileName = "Localized_en.txt";
            break;
    }

    if (localizedStrings.empty()) {
        // Initialize variables needed
        ssize_t fileSize = 0;
        unsigned char * fileContents = NULL;
        string line, fullPath, contents;

        // Get absolute path of file
        fullPath = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename( fileName );
        cout << "fullPath: " << fullPath << endl;

        // Get data of file
        if( !fullPath.empty() ) {
            fileContents = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->getFileData( fullPath.c_str( ) , "rb", &fileSize );
            cout << "fileContents: " << fileContents << endl;
            contents.assign(fileContents,fileContents+fileSize-1);

            // Create a string stream so that we can use getline( ) on it
            istringstream fileStringStream( contents );

            // Get file contents line by line
            while ( std::getline( fileStringStream, line ) )
            {
                //filter the valid string of one line
                if (line.find("/*",0) == string::npos && line.find("//",0) == string::npos)                 {
                    std::string::size_type validPos= line.find('=',0);
                    if ( validPos != string::npos)
                    {
                        std::string keyStr = line.substr(0,validPos-1);
                        std::string subStr = line.substr(validPos+1,line.size()-1); // get valid string

                        //trim space
                        keyStr.erase(0, keyStr.find_first_not_of(" \t")); // remove head white-space
                        keyStr.erase(keyStr.find_last_not_of(" \t") + 1); // remove tail white-space

                        subStr.erase(0, subStr.find_first_not_of(" \t")); // remove head white-space
                        subStr.erase(subStr.find_last_not_of(" \t") + 1); // remove tail white-space

                        //trim \"
                        keyStr.erase(0, keyStr.find_first_not_of("\""));
                        keyStr.erase(keyStr.find_last_not_of("\"") + 1);
                        subStr.erase(0, subStr.find_first_not_of("\""));

                        //trim ; character and last \" character
                        subStr.erase(subStr.find_last_not_of(";") + 1);
                        subStr.erase(subStr.find_last_not_of("\"") + 1);

                        //replace line feed with \n
                        string::size_type pos(0);
                        string old_value("\\n");
                        if((pos=subStr.find(old_value))!=string::npos)
                        {
                            for(; pos!=string::npos; pos+=1)
                            {
                                if((pos=subStr.find(old_value,pos))!=string::npos)
                                {
                                    subStr.erase(pos, 2);
                                    subStr.insert(pos, 1, '\n');
                                }
                                else
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        localizedStrings.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(keyStr,subStr));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //must delete fileContents
        if (fileContents!= NULL) {
            delete [] fileContents;
            fileContents = NULL;
        }
    }

    cout << "key: " + key << endl;
    logMap(localizedStrings);
    if( localizedStrings.find(key) != localizedStrings.end() ) {
        return localizedStrings.at(key);
    }
    cclog("return key instead");
    return key;
}
```

**UPDATED**
OMG, I found it seems to be relative with the position of text in the file. only the key-value in the FIRST line of file will cause the problem.
but I still don't know why........

this is the content of the localized string file:

```
S_TEST = Test777
S_HELLO = hello123
S_WARNING_UNABLE_TO_PUT_INTO_WEREHOUSE = teest13124
```

see? if I access the key S_HELLO and S_WARNINGxxx, it works fine. but if I access the key S_TEST, it will crash....

Comment: [Works fine](https://ideone.com/dc99PZ), **show your complete code**.

Comment: Sorry for a first comment about more complete code. I think (but will have to check) that the issue is that a temporary is constructed from the literal, and a reference to that temporary is then used when the temporary has been destroyed.

Comment: No, the temporary idea doesn't hold up (there is such a problem with `std::pair`, but it doesn't manifest here). Please post complete code, and info about your compiler and the build command.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking there's just a difference in S_HELLO as compiled and the localized version in his data file... could be some encoding thing. Might need to view the binary for the string. To test this theory, just insert "S_HELLO" into the map right before dumping the map, and see if it comes out twice. This would prove there's some invisible difference.

Comment: Thought 1: Make sure `0` is not `O`. Thought 2: See if `std::string("S_HELLO")` equals what you believe is the key that it should match.

Comment: well, I try to access another key "S_TEST", it won't crash... but it will still crash if I access the key "S_HELLO", and I am sure the character is "O" not "0"(zero). wtf? why access another key is safe? ~"~

Comment: You said, your input file is UTF8. std::string is not an UTF8. In your load, you do substrings and trims. It is possible, that for S_HELLO, you load some invisible char from input file, that mess your key

Comment: @MartinPerry ya, I think it might be the reason. see my updated, it only has crash problem when I try to access the FIRST key in the localized file.

Comment: @MartinPerry BTW, you say std::string is not an UTF8. so how I should modify the code?

Comment: @firestoke For UTF8, you have to use some 3rd party library (try http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) instead of std::string

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem only with the first key in your file, then you have most likely a `BOM` (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of your file. These are 2 invisible bytes, which are inserted by default in UTF-8 files by many Windows editors.

To remove the `BOM` open the file with Notepad++. In the `Encoding` menu select `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`. Then save the file again.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this crash problem seems to be due to reading certain invisible characters from the localized txt file at the first line.

so I do a work-around solution: just insert a comment text at first line, then problem solved. It might be the file is UTF-8 format, so it contains some UTF-8 format header at the beginning of file, and it should not be read into the string map.

```
// !!LEAVE THE FIRST LINE EMTPY!!
S_TEST = Test777
S_HELLO = hello123
S_WARNING_UNABLE_TO_PUT_INTO_WEREHOUSE = Unable to put into werehouse
```

Answer (score 0):

the difference between map::at and map::[] is that at will check if the key exists in a map. If key does not exist it will throw an exception. Operator [] will add a new key in a map instead. In your case the map doesn't crash but throws exception. Either add a key into the map or handle exception or use operator [] instead of at.